# Is there an easy way to reverse pretty print of json in vim?

Tags: python, json, bash, vim, pretty-print

When I label images or text for Machine Learning purposes, I often export the results in a `json` format. Then, I can open it in `vim` and simply pretty print using

```
:execute '%!python -m json.tool'
```

I often add `| w` which automatically writes changes to the file.

Is there a way to reverse this process? To compact the json, so there are no redundant characters?

#### Example input:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "email": "john@smith.co.uk"
}
```

#### Desired output:

```
{"name":"John","email":"john@smith.co.uk"}
```

I would be fulfilled with Vimish, Pythonish and Bashish solution.

Comment: Would you be willing to use `:%!jq -c .` instead?

Comment: @chepner would you post it as an answer and break the 300k?

Comment: do you want to join all lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [`chepner`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) mentioned in the comment the solution is to use:

```
:%!jq -c .
```

I have tested it and it works.

In case, one wants to save the file immediately, they can add `| w` to write changes.

This requires `jq` installed on the system which is quite a standard utility.

Comment: It works... if `jq` is installed. It is hardly a standard utility expected to be present by default on most systems. (+1, but I think this clarification was needed.)

Answer (score 4):

This could also be done in pure Vim:

```
%delete | 0put =json_encode(json_decode(@@))
```

But note that the field order within an object will not be preserved. So you can get

```
{"email":"john@smith.co.uk","name":"John"}
```

Comment: That should be fine; JSON itself doesn't require that key order be preserved when decoding.

Comment: @chepner Sure. Neither VimScript has key order for Dictionary type, and that's why it may change. I only mention this, because the OP is actualy about "pretty printing".